# setTimeout memory leak in Titanium Appcelerator

Tags: javascript, titanium-mobile

I've done a little bit of research and have found that using setTimeout() causes a bad memory leak, as seen on [this post](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/71241/memory-leaks-releasing-memory). I'm hoping to find a remedy or an alternative.

What I have is a small view appearing on the screen when any of my many buttons is touched. At the same time I set a timeout to fadeout the small view after 3 seconds. When the button is first pressed, I also clear the timeout so that I don't continue setting multiple ones. Though now while analyzing my code I see that I'm setting an interval and clearing a timeout. Not sure if this is part of my issue. It looks like this:

```
var Modal = Titanium.UI.createView({
    width:151,
    height:83,
    owner: null,
    myView: null,
});

var modalTimer;
var addModal = function(){
    clearInterval(modalTimer);
    theView.add(Modal);
    modalTimer = setTimeout( function() {
        removeModal();
        changeTurn();
},3000);
}

playerButton.addEventListener('click',function(){
    addModal(); 
});
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Opposite to what you mentioned in your question you are calling `setTimeout()` and `clearInterval()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have solved this issue with the following:

```
var Modal = Titanium.UI.createView({
    width:151,
    height:83,
    owner: null,
    myView: null,
});

var modalTimer;
var addModal = function(){
    clearTimeout(modalTimer);
    theView.add(Modal);
    modalTimer = setTimeout(removeModal(),3000);
}

playerButton.addEventListener('click',function(){
    addModal(); 
});
```

I put my changeTurn() function in my removeModal() function, and removed the anonymous function from setTimeout. I also corrected the clearTimeout confusion. I still have to see how well this holds up over extended gameplay, but from first impressions this has fixed my issues. I hope this helps anyone with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps but I have noticed that my app crashes if i use:

```
modalTimer = setTimeout(removeModal(),3000);
```

but doesn't if i use

```
modalTimer = setTimeout(removeModal, 3000);
```

where removeModal is defined as

```
var removeModal = function()
{...};
```

Comment: -1: `setTimeout` takes a function as a parameter, not the result of a function call. `removeModal()` wouldn't be expected to work.